# Toolbar put background transparent to avoid wrong background in cursor

Tags: android, layout, toolbar

[image]

I trying to set the background of a toolbar `transparent` to avoid a blank background in the cursors. When we use a `SearchView`.

This is the style that I have now

```
    <style name="theme_toolbar" >
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#454545</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#454545</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FF9F00</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#454545</item>
    <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#767676</item>
</style>
```

And the Toolbar in the layout

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/theme_toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
```

And now I want it, instead of the `black background` I want a `white background`

And If i change `<item name="android:background">#00000000</item>` to         `<item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>`. The cursor have a white background. And I don't want that.

[image]

Comment: Change `<item name="android:background">#00000000[![enter image description here][1]][1]</item>` to `<item name="android:background">#FFFFFF[![enter image description here][1]][1]</item>`

Comment: Yes, i try it. but i I do it. The cursor have a white background...

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine in your code Just Make sure your Activity's theme is `NoActionBar`

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```